# Bone rotation gone wrong on mocap!

Tags: rigging, bones, motion-capture

I really need you guys help.
Well, I have this ugly mocap:

[image: Armature_MOCAP]

And like all mocap, need my rig to follow it.
But the hand rotation is screwing up, no matter what I do.

[image: Mesh_BoneWrong_01]

Seems like the hand rotation is jumping the keyframes.

[image: Mesh_BoneWrong_02]

And sometimes the palm of the hand is facing the wrong direction.
I don't know if you guys can explain to me how to get it right, sometimes explain is harder than do it.

I included the project file to better visualization of what I'm trying to say, but if you fix it and don't want to explain, it's ok for me too LOL.
Thanks!!
[Blender File](https://www.4shared.com/file/HX8WwnEAda/OP_Armature_NOHEAD.html)

Comment: I can't download it, could you please share your file on another site? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [Blender File](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6426/)  

Reuploaded! It was too big for blend-exchange, but I managed it.

Comment: I'm not used to this kind of rigging, it looks like your armature called HUGO_ANIM is supposed to follow the one called Armature with a lot of constraints, is there a reason for that and not directly use Armature? I may be not the one who can advise you...   :/

Comment: There's kinda reason. The software that I'm extracting the mocap don't give me an armature, but empties. So I have to make an armature to Copy Location of an empty and Track To another, so I can Copy Rotation from my main armature called HUGO_ANIM. I jerry-rigged.

Comment: I can't see it, when does it happen? It's very jittered and incoherent but I don't think it comes from a problem caused by the armature, I guess it's rather related to the motion capture, for arms and hands you have one keyframe per frame but there must be some interpretation problems

Comment: Don't mind the jittering or anything caused by the bad mocap, the problem is the hand rotation. :/